# Where and how can one test plasma or sharding on testnet?

Tags: plasma, sharding

Is there a good tutorial on how to test out plasma or sharding for Ethereum 2.0 on testnet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Plasma, https://plasma.group states 3 steps.

[image]

Their site and [Github](https://github.com/plasma-group/plasma-chain-operator) has more information.